# Ideal generated by a subset

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I know that if ring $R$ is commutative, then $\forall a\in R$, the ideal generated by $a$ is $<a>=aR$. I was wondering if the converse is also true. If $<a>=aR, \forall a\in R$, is $R$ commutative? What if I change "$\forall a\in R$" to "for some $a\in R$" ?

Comment: If you change it to some $a\in R$, then it is false. Take $a=1$.

Comment: What do you mean by “ideal generated by $a$” if $R$ is not necessarily commutative?